# How to get HTML source code from an url in blackberry

Tags: blackberry

I want to get the source code of a webpage. I am using `HttpConnection` 
following is my code..

```
HttpConnection c = null;
         InputStream dis = null;
         StringBuffer raw = new StringBuffer();
         try {

                c = (HttpConnection)Connector.open(txtUrl.getText().toString());

             int len = 0;
             int size = 0;
             dis = c.openInputStream();
             byte[] data = new byte[256];
             while ( -1 != (len = dis.read(data)) ){

                 raw.append(new String(data, 0, len));
             size += len;    

             }
             System.out.println("Html source"+raw.toString());

         }  catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
             System.out.println("Exception " +e);
            }
         finally {
             if (dis != null)
                try {
                    dis.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    System.out.println("Exception " +e);
                }
             if (c != null)
                try {
                    c.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    System.out.println("Exception " +e);
                }
         }
```

At this line `dis = c.openInputStream();` i am getting error as source not found - datagramProtocol(ConnectionBase).receive(Datagram). 
Where I am going wrong please correct me..

Comment: Perhaps you could add some information about what is happening that is not expected?  For example, "I expect to see 'HTML source <html>...' but what I really see is 'HTML source blah blah...'" or "I am receiving a NullPointerException at line xyz" or similar.

Comment: Source not found is not an error, but the debugger is unable to find the source code that goes with the code that has thrown an exception. We really need to know what exception is thrown, and what message is contained in the exception, if any.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should probably read the API documentation for [javax.microedition.io.HttpConnection](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/4.0.2api/javax/microedition/io/HttpConnection.html) and implement your input routine as recommended there.